# Javascript - generating a random number of specified length from set of specified values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to generate a random number 32 characters in length from a specified set of characters.

For example:

```
var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZ";
var string_length = 32;
```

Which would then return a random number of length 32 using the specified characters.

Comment: Since when can a number contain letters? :)

Comment: This sounds like homework. What have you tried? What do have diffculties with? The loop? The randomness? Show what you have tried. BTW, jQuery wouldn't play into this at all.

Comment: ...by the way, your `chars` string has two Ts in it :-P

Comment: @Nick: Clearly it's a base-36 number. I only wish I were geeky enough to know what the appropriate prefix for 36 is so I could say "blahblahdecimal". :-) (Google says "triántaéxidecimal")

Comment: @Andy: *Please* tell me you just happened to see that. You didn't...check. ;-)

Comment: @T.J. I noticed in someone else's answer and was just about to reply to them when it occurred to me that they probably just copied it from the question.  Surprisingly enough, my brain told me there was something odd about the character sitting between X and Z ;-)

Comment: No this wasn't hoomework.  I was just massively hungover and desperately had to get an answer.

I would not normally post such questions but am a beginner at JS and struggle to get my head round some of the concepts even when i am sober.  

I very much appreciate all answers and comments, i really do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZ";
var string_length = 32;
var myrnd = [], pos;

// loop as long as string_length is > 0
while (string_length--) {
    // get a random number between 0 and chars.length - see e.g. http://www.shawnolson.net/a/789/make-javascript-mathrandom-useful.html
    pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
    // add the character from the base string to the array
    myrnd.push(chars.substr(pos, 1));
}

// join the array using '' as the separator, which gives us back a string
myrnd.join(''); // e.g "6DMIG9SP1KDEFB4JK5KWMNSI3UMQSSNT"
```

Comment: This is obviously a beginner. If you give a finished answer you should at least give some remarks in what you are doing, because things like counting down the length in the `while` condition or the using an array and joining it are not easy to understand, if you are still working on the basics.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

Check out the jsfiddle. I modified it so you can see the progression as the result grows: http://jsfiddle.net/YuyNL/

```
var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZ";   // Pool of potential characters
var string_length = 32;                     // Desired length of result
var num_chars = chars.length;               // Total number of characters in pool
var result = '';                      // Container to store result

while(string_length--) {      // Run a loop for a duration equal to the length of the result

  // For each iteration, get a random number from 0 to the size of the
  //   number of characters you're using, use that number to grab the index
  //   of the character stored in 'chars', and add it to the end of the result

    result += chars[ Math.floor( Math.random() * num_chars ) ];  

}

$('body').append(result + '<br>');  // This just appends the result to the 'body'
                                    //    if you're using jQuery
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Set up a return variable
var randStr = "";

// Split the chars into individual array elements
chars = chars.split("");

// Until string_length is 0...
while (string_length--)
    // ... select a random character from the array
    randStr += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];

// return the string
return randStr;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution that should be quite easy to understand.

```
var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZ";
var string_length = 32;
var result = "";

for(var i=0; i<string_length; i++){
  var randomPos = Math.floor( Math.random() * chars.length );
  result += chars.substr(randomPos, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe make it a little more flexible.

You may want the return to be an array,
if you are going to do any big integer math on it

```
function charsRandom(len, chars){
    chars= chars || "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    len= len || 32;
    var cr= [], L= chars.length;
    while(len--) cr[cr.length]= chars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*L));
    return cr.join(''); // or return the array cr
}
```

alert(charsRandom())